# NameError: name 'swde' is not defined. Как приручить версию Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Ubuntu 18
Код моего скрипта Python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image
outnamefile = str(input("имя выходного файла: "))
im = Image.open("1.jpg")
out = im.thumbnail(700, 700)
out.save(outnamefile + ".jpg", "jpeg")
```

При выполнении его в Pycharm всё без ошибок. При выполнении кода двойным кликом на файл со скриптом (стоит галочка "разрешить выполнение файла, как программы"), выдается ошибка:

```
 имя выходного файла: swde
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "resize_img.py", line 4, in <module>
        outnamefile = str(input("имя выходного файла: "))
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'swde' is not defined
```

Если запускать скрипт через терминал: python3 resize_ing.py
Всё работает хорошо. 
Хоть и шебанг заполнен правильно, скрипт похоже выполняется через Python2.

**Как исправить, чтобы кликом по файлу исполнялся скрип версией python предназначенной для того или иного скрипта?**

Питон стоит 3.6.

```
Команда ~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: outnamefile = str(input("имя выходного файла: ")). Тут конкретно str - не важна. Забыл перед публикацией вопроса поправить. Ругается на input.

Comment: Да. Читайте внимательнее: (стоит галочка "разрешить выполнение файла, как программы"). ну или -х.

Comment: А, да, невнимательно прочитал. Тогда-то другому: двойной клик в каком файловом менеджере-то?

Comment: "Файлы 3.26.3" дефолтный менеждер ubuntu18. По настройкам как наутилус.

Comment: Мой Nautilus 3.26.3 в моей убунте 18 отлично слушается шебанга и запускает всё третьим питоном

Comment: Перепроверьте настройки наутилуса. Может, вы там всюду накосячили и для исполняемых текстовых файлов стоит не «Запустить», а «Показать» и в качестве текстового редактора выбран второй питон?)

Comment: Вот и ломаю по этому голову! В пайшарме или если конкретно указать запуск через пит3 - всё ок. но этоне совсем удобно.

Comment: У меня: настройки - поведение - исполняемые текстовые файлы - спросить что делать. После клика выбираю запустить в терминале.

Comment: Ну тогда даже не знаю, у меня всё отлично https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDV3t.gif

Comment: Да, действительно. Просто скрипт без левых зависимостей работает нормально. Юзаю Pillow на питон3. И только в этих скриптах такие косяки. Скорее всего проблемы с pillow 5. [https://yadi.sk/i/doamAjds3aj8Qx]. Хотя через пайшарм работает отлично. Что странно @andreymal

Comment: Ваш скрипт в принципе не может работать нигде и никак, потому что вы передаёте неправильные аргументы в im.thumbnail, и в моём Pillow на третьем питоне из-за этого падает ошибка https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail (скриншот ошибки https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsx15.png)

Comment: Нашел и исправил. Всё работает. 'im.thumbnail((700, 700))' Кортеж помещаем в скобки. Спасибо за наводку @andreymal